# Wait until View is visible on Activity

Tags: android, listview, view

I want to get Child Views from ListView, however, the method

`listview.getChildAt(pos)` returns `null` if the View is not actually visible on screen. Calling the method at the tail of

`protected void onCreate(Bundle saved)` also returns `null` because it seems that the background process for inflating the view is still running in the background. How can I check that the View is actually visible on screen before calling `getchildAt(pos)` . I have tried using a timer of 30ms, and it does return the right object at that time, but I do not want to use values hard-coded into the app.

Edit Code:

I am attempting to modify the background colors of individual items dynamically:

```
View view = list.getChildAt(list.getFirstVisiblePosition());

View.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));
```

Comment: code?  you likely need to move your call to onResume() method

Comment: Just to make clear what you are trying to accomplish: I assume you want to change that `ListView` item view. You should better modify the adapter behind the `ListView` in order to do any changes. That's much more reliable than trying to do it from outside. Maybe you could tell us a bit more what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have added the code. adding it to onResume() does not work. I want to set a different color for each item in list view, so I am using the list.getChildAt() method, and will run through a loop to set the colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am attempting to modify the background colors of individual items
>   dynamically

the easiest way to accomplish that in a ListView is probably by extending/customizing your adapter.

for example:

```
list.setAdapter = new ArrayAdapter( /* do here all initialisation of the adapter */){

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
         v.setBackgroundColor( /* your color goes here */ );
    }
}
```

of course you can use that to any type of adapter, including if it's your own CustomAdapter, just put in there.

Comment: Thanks! Worked Perfectly!